# Measuring current using low side shunt method (MCLV-2 board)

Tags: pic, current-measurement

I am trying to measure the current through the MOSFET switch M1 using low side shunt resistor method (on MCLV-2 dev. board).  I can read the signal `Vout' on the analog input of a dsPIC33F MCU. I believe that the capacitors are there to filter high frequency switching noise and clean up the measurement. Converting the ADC reading from MCU to a meaningful current reading in amperes requires solving this circuit. So I used a simplified circuit to apply the circuit theory to solve for the voltages. I arrived at the simplified circuit using the fact that in steady state the capacitor will behave as an open circuit. I came up with the following equations:

```
Vn = Vp                       (negative feedback)
(V1 - Vn)/2K = (Vn - V3)/30K   (KCL at node Vn with shown current direction)
(Vref - Vp)/30K + (V2 - Vp)/2K = 0      (KCL at node Vp with shown current direction)
```

My questions are: **(1)** Is the simplified circuit correct? **(2)** Are these equations correct? **(3)** Do I need knowledge of `V1' and`V2' for solving this circuit? Any other help regarding this will also be greatly appreciated!
The schematics of the original and simplified circuit are shown below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTVAFT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnSfJ4.png)</sup>

Comment: Why are you using two current sense resistors of 25 milli ohm?

Comment: @Andy, This is a simplified schematic. The actual circuit is a 3-legged bridge, too large to put here. The lower current sense was added to show that V2 terminal was not hooked to ground. Hope it clarifies:)

Comment: How can this be analysed without full knowledge of the shunt?

Comment: Ideally, looks to me like it's a differential amplifier with a gain of -15 times the input current*R1, referenced to Vref, 1.36V.  So for a current of 1A there would be 25mV across the sense resistor, and 1.36-.375V = .985V at the output of the op-amp.  This of course ignores resistor mismatch CMR errors, offset errors, etc.

Comment: @Andyaka the edited schematic should clarify things.

Comment: @JohnD is the information of V1 and V2 is not needed if Vout is known?

Comment: Yes, they are not needed, see Bruce's comments below.

Answer (score 2):

> (1) Is the simplified circuit correct?

Yes. It is a valid simplification of your 'original' circuit.

> (2) Are these equations correct?

Yes (though they might be easier to solve if you define Vref as 'ground').

> (3) Do I need knowledge of V1' and V2' for solving this circuit?

No. The formula for a differential op amp is Vout = (V2-V1)*Rf/Rin, so you only need to know the voltage *difference* between V1 and V2. This voltage is determined by the resistance of R1 and the current flowing through it.

NOTE: In your circuit current flows from V1 to V2, so Vout will go negative (relative to Vref) for positive current. However the MCLV-2 board's amplifier inputs are connected in reverse compared to your circuit, so their output voltages will not be inverted. Also the reference voltage is 1.65V (3.3V/2) not 1.36V.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. **(1)** Which resistance you are referring to by `Rin`? **(2)** Also, with knowledge of `Vout`, `Rf` and `Rin`, current through the shunt resistor `R1` is simply `(V2-V1)/R1`, correct? **(3)** If you are referring to the amplifier OA1 in the above schematic, it is connected as shown in the MCLV-2 schematic. I did not follow what you meant by _are connected in reverse compared to your circuit_. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: **(1)** Rin = 2k in your simplified circuit. **(2)** The voltage across R1 is V1-V2. In the gain equation it is changed to V2-V1 to match the op amp inputs (output goes positive when V2 > V1). **(3)** in the MCLV-2 schematic, SHUNT_HI_SUM is below the shunt resistor and SHUNT_HI_x is above it. You may be confused because they _appear_ to be the other way around in sheet 2.

Comment: just out of curiosity, have you worked with an MCLV-2 or answered just by looking at is datasheet?

Comment: I just looked at the datasheet.

Comment: Comment on **NOTE** in the answer: `Vout = Vref + (Rf/Rin)*(V2 - V1)`. So with positive current flow, `Vout` will go negative only if `Vref=0`. In the case of MCLV-2, `Vref` is `1.65V`, hence `Vout` will go negative whenever the term `(Rf/Rin)*(V2 - V1) < -1.65V`.